# Simplest way to perform grouping/projection using Linq To Objects

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, projection, linq-group

I'm getting data from the data layer that I need to transform in the middle tier using Linq To Objects (I don't control that tier of the application).  I have to perform a grouping operation using multiple keys followed by a string concatenation on the non key-fields.  Given the data below, I want to group by CustomerID and Date, and create a new structure in which only a single row is generated based on the key, and the non key field (in this case Item) gets combined into one string:

```
    CustomerID  Date         Item
    A          11/1/2001    Bread
    A          11/1/2001        Orange Juice
    A          11/1/2001        Salad Dressing
    B          11/1/2001    Bananas
    C          5/6/2001     Candy
    C          12/8/2005    Candy               


    CustomerID  Date         Item
    A          11/1/2001    Bread
                             Orange Juice
                             Salad Dressing
    B          11/1/2001    Bananas
    C          5/6/2001     Candy
    C          12/8/2005    Candy
```

Is this possible using the functional style linq syntax or do I have to resort to old-school imperative foreach syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var result = from item in items
             group item by new { item.Date, item.CustomerID } into g
             select new
             {
                 g.Key.CustomerID,
                 g.Key.Date,
                 Item = string.Join(", ", from i in g select i.Item)
             };
```

Comment: Only the .Min date? Doesn't it need to be grouped twice?

Comment: You changed it before I could finish posting the comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

```
var results = items
  .GroupBy(i => new { i.Date, i.CustomerID })
  .Select(g => new {
    CustomerID = g.Key.CustomerID,
    Date = g.Key.Date,
    Item = string.Join(", ", g.Select(i => i.Item).ToArray())
  });
```

Comment: I wrote up the same thing in VS, but the compiler complained about including an IEnumerable<> as a parameter to string.Join().  This will work: "g.Select(i => i.Item).ToArray()".

Comment: @Jimmy W: [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) has an overload that takes any IEnumerable<> since .NET 4.0.

Comment: Ah, I was using .NET 3.5.  Makes sense.

Comment: Am using .NET 3.5; Sorry should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Dirk: Then just add `.ToArray` as *@Jimmy W* indicated, and you should be fine.